# Using CompanionDeviceManager to read the devices information

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am using `BluetoothLeScanner` to scan for BLE devices and get a list of objects representing the devices to show inside my app (not connecting to any of them).

I am interested in doing the same, but using the `CompanionDeviceManager` now. Its callback `CompanionDeviceManager.Callback.onDeviceFound(chooserLauncher: IntentSender?)` unfortunately does not return any human readable form of found devices... the closest it gets is the `IntentSender.writeToParcel` method, but I am not sure how to use it in this situation.

I am not constrained to use the `CompanionDeviceManager` but I wanted to follow the OS version specific guidelines, we are supposed to use `CompanionDeviceManager` for Bluetooth devices scanning starting from API 26, but it seems useless in my case... so is there any way to get devices data from that callback, or should I just ditch it and stay with `BluetoothLeScanner` for all OS versions?

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but it might help someone else. You can create a bluetooth device picker in combination with `ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()` in order to get the `BluetoothDevice`. From there you will have access to all the device info that you need. Recent changes added some Android 12 permissions like `android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT`. Your mileage may vary.

```
    val context = LocalContext.current

    // Get the device manager instance
    val deviceManager: CompanionDeviceManager by lazy {
        ContextCompat.getSystemService(
            context,
            CompanionDeviceManager::class.java
        ) as CompanionDeviceManager
    }

    // Create a filter of your choice. Here I just look for specific device names
    val deviceFilter: BluetoothDeviceFilter by lazy {
        BluetoothDeviceFilter.Builder()
            .setNamePattern(Pattern.compile(supportedDevices))
            .build()
    }

    // Create a pairing request with your filter from the last step
    val pairingRequest: AssociationRequest = AssociationRequest.Builder()
        .addDeviceFilter(deviceFilter)
        .build()

    // Create a picker for discovered bluetooth devices
    val bluetoothDevicePicker = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(),
        onResult = {
            val device: BluetoothDevice? =
                it.data?.getParcelableExtra(CompanionDeviceManager.EXTRA_DEVICE)
            try {
                // Now that you have the desired device, do what you need to with it
                device?.apply {
                    when {
                        name?.matches(Regex(firstDevicePattern)) == true -> {
                            Log.i(TAG, "${this.name} connected")
                            onFirstDeviceDiscovered(device)
                        }
                        name?.matches(Regex(secondDevicePattern)) == true -> {
                            Log.i(TAG, "${this.name} connected")
                            onSecondDeviceDiscovered(device)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: SecurityException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                //TODO: handle the security exception (this is possibly a bug)
                // https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/198986283
            }
        }
    )

    // A utility function to centralize calling associate (optional)
    val associateDevice: (AssociationRequest) -> Unit = { request ->
        // Attempt to associate device(s)
        deviceManager.associate(
            request,
            object : CompanionDeviceManager.Callback() {

                override fun onDeviceFound(chooserLauncher: IntentSender) {
                    val sender = IntentSenderRequest.Builder(chooserLauncher)
                        .build()
                    bluetoothDevicePicker.launch(sender)
                }

                override fun onFailure(error: CharSequence?) {
                    //TODO: handle association failure
                }
            }, null
        )
    }
```